# How to recover the exception info from .gcc_except_table and .eh_handle sections?

Tags: c++, exception, assembly, x86, elf

For `C++` program with `try` `catch` defined, when using `g++` to compile it into assembly code (test is on x86 32bit Linux, `g++` 4.6.3)

```
g++ -S cppexcept.cc
```

A specified section called `.gcc_except_table` is produced like below:

```
        .section        .gcc_except_table
        .align 4
.LLSDA980:
        .byte   0xff
        .byte   0
        .uleb128 .LLSDATT980-.LLSDATTD980
.LLSDATTD980:
        .byte   0x1
        .uleb128 .LLSDACSE980-.LLSDACSB980
.LLSDACSB980:
        .uleb128 .LEHB3-.LFB980
        .uleb128 .LEHE3-.LEHB3
        .uleb128 0
        .uleb128 0
        .uleb128 .LEHB4-.LFB980
        .uleb128 .LEHE4-.LEHB4
        .uleb128 .L19-.LFB980
        .uleb128 0x3
        .uleb128 .LEHB5-.LFB980
        .uleb128 .LEHE5-.LEHB5
        .uleb128 0
        .uleb128 0
        .uleb128 .LEHB6-.LFB980
        .uleb128 .LEHE6-.LEHB6
        .uleb128 .L20-.LFB980
        .uleb128 0
        .uleb128 .LEHB7-.LFB980
        .uleb128 .LEHE7-.LEHB7
        .uleb128 .L21-.LFB980
        .uleb128 0
```

After the compilation into `exe file` with `ELF` format, it seems that there are two sections related to exception handling, which are `.gcc_except_table` and `.eh_frame`.

However, I dumped the contents of these two section with the following commands, comparing the labels' memory addresses with what are defined in `.gcc_except_table`, but it seems too blur to me...

```
objdump -s -j .gcc_except_table cppexcept
objdump -s -j .eh_frame cppexcept
```

So my question is:

Is there any way to recover the information defined in the `.gcc_except_table` (which is shown above) from `ELF` file's `.gcc_except_table` and `eh_frame` tables?

Comment: [Answered](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6312/60) on RE.SE. Please don't cross-post, it's [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/211127).